# How to get the size of a file in NAnt

Tags: nant, nantcontrib

Does NAnt or NAntContrib have a way to get the size of a file?  I have searched the docs for both, but don't see one.

Or is the best way to either shell out to a command line or write an inline C# script?

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522261/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-directory-in-nant) for getting the size of a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [file::get-length Function](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/file.get-length%28System.String%29.html).